Cannot run web application on Nectar Virtual Machine due to qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found
I just launched my first virtual machine instance using Nectar with Ubuntu 22.04.4 and looking to use it to host a web application that my team developed using node.js. However, when I use npm run dev to start the web application, I get the following error:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

I tried to use the below command but it did not work
sudo apt install libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-render-util0

Also, I'm not sure if Qt is already installed on my virtual machine. I don't know how to install Qt on virtual machine as I can only access it by connecting to it using command prompt and from what I search, it seems that I can't install Qt using the terminal.
I am new to launching a virtual machine and hosting web application on it. How do I fix this problem
